# How to replace values in an xts object based on conditions from other xts object

Tags: r, replace, xts

I have two xts objects.

The first one "stocks_purchase_dates" contains the opening dates and purchase prices of 4 stocks.

```
stocks_purchase_dates             

           stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
2018-03-19     NA     NA     NA 165.78
2018-03-21     NA   36.1     NA     NA
2018-03-23     23     NA     NA     NA
2018-03-26     NA     NA  48.81     NA
```

The second one "stocks_prices_mar15_mar28" contains the prices of the 4 stocks for the period March 15 - March 28, 2018.

```
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28                         

           stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
2018-03-15  23.30  44.28  54.75 177.34
2018-03-16  23.06  45.12  55.10 176.72
2018-03-19  23.31  44.44  54.31 174.02
2018-03-20  23.75  44.82  54.06 173.96
2018-03-21  23.92  43.19  53.91 170.02
2018-03-22  23.47  41.27  51.68 167.61
2018-03-23  23.43  39.96  49.90 163.73
2018-03-26  24.16  38.27  51.68 171.50
2018-03-27  23.40  37.19  50.10 167.11
2018-03-28  23.27  36.99  50.94 165.26
```

In "stocks_prices_mar15_mar28", I want to replace the values of each stock before the opening date (given in "stocks_purchase_dates") with 0s.

One possible solution is to replace by column and dates:

```
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[,"stock1"]["/2018-03-22", ] <- 0
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[,"stock2"]["/2018-03-20", ] <- 0
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[,"stock3"]["/2018-03-25", ] <- 0
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[,"stock4"]["/2018-03-18", ] <- 0
```

The output is:

```
stocks_prices_mar15_mar28             

           stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
2018-03-15   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-03-16   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-03-19   0.00   0.00   0.00 165.78
2018-03-20   0.00   0.00   0.00 173.96
2018-03-21   0.00  36.10   0.00 170.02
2018-03-22   0.00  41.27   0.00 167.61
2018-03-23  23.00  39.96   0.00 163.73
2018-03-26  24.16  38.27  48.81 171.50
2018-03-27  23.40  37.19  50.10 167.11
2018-03-28  23.27  36.99  50.94 165.26
```

It works, but if we have a lot more stocks and opening dates it will become hardwork and complicated.

Is there any way to accomplish the task more efficiently, for example with apply or for loop or a function from the purrr package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `for` loop to loop over the column names. With `!is.na(stocks_purchase_dates$stock1)` you can find which stock1 record is not `NA`. With `which` you can find the position of this record. With `.index` you can filter inside an xts object. So what we can do is check if the index of stocks_prices_mar15_mar28 is lower than the index of record of stocks_purchase_dates we find looking with `which` and `!is.na` and then set those records to 0.

Now this only works if per stock there is only 1 purchase record in stocks_purchase_dates.

```
for(i in names(stocks_purchase_dates)) {
  stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[, i][.index(stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[, i]) < index(stocks_purchase_dates[, i])[which(!is.na(stocks_purchase_dates[, i]))]] <- 0
}

stocks_prices_mar15_mar28
           stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
2018-03-15   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-03-16   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-03-19   0.00   0.00   0.00 174.02
2018-03-20   0.00   0.00   0.00 173.96
2018-03-21   0.00  43.19   0.00 170.02
2018-03-22   0.00  41.27   0.00 167.61
2018-03-23  23.43  39.96   0.00 163.73
2018-03-26  24.16  38.27  51.68 171.50
2018-03-27  23.40  37.19  50.10 167.11
2018-03-28  23.27  36.99  50.94 165.26
```

When copying and replacing values in the code, be careful of all brackets and braces.

Comment: Thank you very much @phiver. Your answer helps me a lot. Just a small correction on your solution: there is a dot in front of the index [.index(stocks_prices_mar15_mar28[, i] which has to be removed in order the code to work properly.

Comment: It should work with the dot, but it works without it as well. See`?.index` or `?indexClass` for more functions with dot in front of the name. Handy for changing / selecting time components in xts.

Comment: When I executed the code with the dot, it returned "stocks_prices_mar15_mar28" in its initial form without the 0s.